# Can't connect to SQL server while making ADO.NET entity data model

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I think that the picture below is self explanatory.  The problem is that I start adding a ADO.NET Entity data model with database first but whenever I try to do it, I don't get a connection string when I choose the type of connection.  Hope the picture will be of help because I don't know exactly how to describe the problem.

[image]

Comment: opening Services then start or restart running Sql Server

Comment: or RESTART your computer and you will be able to connect to your sql server (localhost)

Comment: Do you have a connection string in your app.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should, open the SQL Server Configuration Manager and

```
1) verify the sql server service is up
2) make sure the server and client protocols are set
3) verify your sql server instance NAME. for ex) . or .\SQLEXPRESS or something else
4) check your firewall
```

best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the State of the SQL Server is "Running". That error always come up if the state is "Stopped"

[image]